# Active Storage raises ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

To import an image file into the Rails app using Active Storage, I wrote a Rake like this:

```
task :import_file => :environment do
  path = Rails.root.join("tmp", "sample.jpg")
  data = File.read(path)

  post = Post.first
  post.image.attach(data)
end
```

When I executed this task, I got an Exception `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature`.

How can I avoid this error?

The source code of `Post` model is:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

I use the default `config/storage.yml`.

```
test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

The version of Rails is 5.2.0.beta2.

Answer (score 8):

On the [Edge API document](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/One.html#method-i-attach), I found the answer.

```
desc "Import file"
task :import_file => :environment do
  path = Rails.root.join("tmp", "sample.jpg")

  post = Post.first
  File.open(path) do |io|
    post.image.attach(io: io, filename: "sample.jpg")
  end
end
```

Comment: Be careful: you're opening one new file handle per image. You have to either close each file you open, or use the block form of `File.open`, which would be the preferred way to do it.

Comment: @FrançoisBeausoleil out of curiosity, what happens if the file handers aren't closed?

Comment: @stevec if you don't close the file handle, you may run out of file handles. There are per-process limits, and depending on your OS, the limit may be quite low, on the order of 1000.

Answer (score 5):

Just leaving my answer here, just in case anyone encounters the same problem as me.

I made the silly mistake of not passing the `resize` key in the argument when creating a `variant`:

```
image_tag user.profile_photo.variant('200x200')
```

Should have passed:

```
image_tag user.profile_photo.variant(resize: '200x200')
```