# Why RSpec throws an InvalidSignature error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am new to Ruby, Rails and TDD, and I'm stuck during a test in my code.
I'm trying to test the creation of a Recipe model, posted by a User created with FactoryBot.

My Recipe model (app/models/recipe.rb) is:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  resourcify

  validates :image, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :preparazione, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes
  has_many :comments

  has_one_attached :image
end
```

In spec/models/recipe_spec.rb I have:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Recipe, type: :model do
  describe "Creating a Recipe" do
    it "should be permitted" do
  
      @user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
      recipe = Recipe.new(title: 'Recipe', 
                          preparazione: 'Preparation',
                          image: '../support/test_image.jpg',
                          user_id: @user.id,
                          n_likes: 0,
                          n_comments: 0,
                          created_at: Time.now.utc)
      expect(recipe).to be_valid
      @user.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

This test fails, and the error is:

```
Failures:

1) Recipe Creating a Recipe should be permitted
 Failure/Error: expect(recipe).to be_valid

 ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature:
   ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature
 # ./spec/models/recipe_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

 Finished in 0.35273 seconds (files took 7.93 seconds to load)
 7 examples, 1 failure

 Failed examples:

 rspec ./spec/models/recipe_spec.rb:5 # Recipe Creating a Recipe should be permitted
```

Why is this error showing up and what does it mean?

Comment: Show us the `Recipe` model class code, please

Comment: `expect(recipe).to be_valid` calls the method: `valid?` on `recipe`. Which, in turn, will run whatever rails validations you have defined on the model. So something in your code **(which you haven't shown us)** is raising that exception as part of the validation flow.

Comment: What's in `app/models/recipe.rb`? What validations did you define? In particular, where's the code that references `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier`?

Comment: Looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48162667/active-storage-raises-activesupportmessageverifierinvalidsignature

Comment: Right, if I remove the validation of the image in the model, the test succeeds. However, I'd still like to have the image required. Can I upload an image in a RSpec test?

Comment: Looks like there's some integration between ActiveStorage and Rails's message signing system... Can you paste the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Instead of a "carpet bombing" test that tells you nothing about what it is testing or why it you fails you should test each validation on its own. The [shoulda-matchers](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers) gem can really help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
recipe = Recipe.new(title: 'Recipe', 
                          preparazione: 'Preparation',
                          image: Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new('spec/support/test_image.jpg', 'image/jpg')), 
                          user_id: @user.id,
                          n_likes: 0,
                          n_comments: 0,
                          created_at: Time.now.utc)
```

Upload attachments using [`Rack::Test::UploadedFile` class](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/master/Rack/Test/UploadedFile#:%7E:text=Wraps%20a%20Tempfile%20with%20a,and%20issue%20a%20multipart%20request.) in Rspec.

Comment: It woked with 
`image: Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(Rails.root.join('spec/support/test_image.jpg'), 'image/jpg')`
Thanks!

Comment: Updated the answer. `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new('spec/support/test_image.jpg', 'image/jpg'))` This should also work.